# How can I garantee that there exists a continuous function such that

Tags: analysis, continuity

How can I guarantee that there exists a continuous function $\psi:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for the specific interval $(a,+\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and specific open $G \subset \mathbb{R}^N$:

$$\psi^{-1}((a,+\infty))=G ?$$

There is a way to construct such functions explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the complement $C$ of $G$ is closed.
If $G\ne\mathbb R^N$ then $C\ne\emptyset$, and $\psi(x)=a+\mathrm{dist}(x,C)$ does the trick. The case $G=\mathbb R^n$ is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If $G=\Bbb R^N$  taek $\Phi(\vec x)=a+\varphi(\|\vec x\|)$ where $\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous functions mapping $[0,+\infty)$ into $(0,+\infty)$ (for exmaple take $\varphi$ to be the polygonal joining $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,1/2^2)$, $(3,2^3)$, $(4,1/2^4)$,...., $(2n-1,2^{2n-1})$, $(2n,1/2^{2n})$,...).

If $G\ne\Bbb R^N$, then $\partial G\ne\varnothing$ and it is closed. Just define $\Phi(\vec x)=a+d(\vec x,\partial G)$ if $\vec x\in G$ and $\Phi(\vec x)=a$ otherwise.